# Show 'is_staff' and 'is_active' to display true/false on front end

Tags: python, django

I am writing a front end admin portal to allow for admins to manage users from a front end perspective. I am trying to get a 'user status' table set up so that admins can get the users current status.

I am using the `is_staff` and `is_active` within the `auth_users` table to get the users status.

I have tried several ways but for some reason I cannot get `is_staff = false` to work.

Here is my current code.

**template.py** *Please note these are two seperate ways and examples of the goal I am trying to get*

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Title</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for active_users in active_users %}
          <tr>
            <td >{{active_users}}</td>
            <td>
              {% if user.is_active %}
                    Active
              {% else %}
                    Not Active
              {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{get_status}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/manage_user/{{active_users.id}}"><i class="bi bi-person-add"></i> Manage User</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

For the is_active, I tried using the tags and filters.

```
<td>
    {% if user.is_active %}
        Active
    {% else %}
       Not Active
    {% endif %}
 </td>
```

I also tried:

```
<td>
    {% if user.is_active %}
        Active
    {% elif user.is_active == False%}
       Not Active
    {% endif %}
 </td>
```

I tried those two options for both `is_active` and `is_staff`. It would always return as "Active".

I also wrote this simple function just to see if this would help:

```
    def get_status():
        if User.objects.filter(is_staff=True):
            return 'Staff'
        else:
            return 'Termed'
```

And then call `{{get_status}}` in the template. No matter what, it always returns as true and either shows "Active" or "Staff". The only way I can get "Not Active" or "Termed" to show is by querying `is_staff=False`.

How can I get the `is_active` and `is_staff` to show "Not Active" or "Termed" in the template?

Comment: You used `user` instead of `active_users`. And BTW using the same variable twice in a `for` loop will only lead to confusion.

Comment: The active_users is a query that I have in my views that grabs a list of all of the users. ```active_users = User.objects.all().order_by(“id”)``` 

Really just trying to see what users are and aren’t staff/active on front end.